# A topological example from Church's undecidability paper

Tags: algebraic-topology, computability, simplicial-complex

A. Church, in his classical paper **An unsolvable problem in elementary number theory** in American Journal of Mathematics Vol. 58 No. 2. (1936), pp. 345-363, (available [here](https://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/fraguas/CC/church-An%20Unsolvable%20Problem%20of%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory.pdf)), wrote:

> There is a class of problems of elementary number 
>   theory which can be stated in the form that it is required to find an
>   effectively calculable function $f$ of $n$ positive integers, such that 
>   $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=2$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for the
>   truth of a certain proposition of elementary number theory involving
>   $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ as free variables.

As an example he gave:

> [...] [A] problem of this class is, for instance, the problem
>   of topology, to find a complete set of effectively calculable invariants of 
>   closed three-dimensional simplicial manifolds under homeomorphisms. This problem
>   can be interpreted as a problem of elementary number theory in view of the 
>   fact that topological complexes are representable by matrices of incidence. 
>   In fact, as is well known, the property of a set of incidence matrices that it 
>   represent a closed three-dimensional manifold, and the property of two sets 
>   of incidence matrices that they represent homeomorphic complexes, can both 
>   be described in purely number-theoretic terms.

I'd like to understand the gist of this example, although it's not needed in the rest of the paper. What's a "topological complex"? Is that a [simplicial complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex)? In which sense can it be represented as incidence matrices, assuming it's the same concept from graph theory?

Comment: I assume it's a simplicial complex, yes. The incidence matrices tell you which $n$-simplices are faces of which $(n+1)$-simplices, generalizing the incidence matrices of graphs (which tell you which vertices are faces of which edges).

Answer (score 1):

Just so that this question does not show up as unanswered:

> I assume it's a simplicial complex, yes. The incidence matrices tell you which n-simplices are faces of which (n+1)-simplices, generalizing the incidence matrices of graphs (which tell you which vertices are faces of which edges). – Qiaochu Yuan Mar 24, 2013 at 1:48

This is certainly correct, and the existence of the necessary matrices is a consequence of the assumption the complexes are finite.